How can I integrate Solana blockchain into my rental application for item rentals?
I am developing and study a rental application where users can rent various items. I want to explore integrating Solana blockchain for handling transactions and rental agreements.
What components of my rental platform would benefit from using Solana?
How can I implement Solana within the rental process?
Are there any resources or tutorials available for learning how to work with Solana in this context?
Thank you so much.
